# uitableview not shown at all

Tags: ios, uitableview

I create a UITableView programmatically and add it to a UIView:

**edit1**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

 previewTableView =  [[UITableView 
       alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.previewView.frame.origin.x, 
                                      self.previewView.frame.origin.y, 
                                      self.previewView.frame.size.width, 
                                      self.previewView.frame.size.height
 )];
previewTableView.delegate   = self;
previewTableView.dataSource = self;
previewTableView.tag        = 1;

[self.previewView addSubview:previewTableView];
}
```

The previewView is created with XIB.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  NSLog(@"Height for row %d",tableView.tag);
  if (tableView.tag == 1)
  {
    CGFloat height=((UIImage*)[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).size.height;
    NSLog(@"section: %i, image height: %f",indexPath.section,height);
    return height;
  }
 return 80;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     if (tableView.tag == 1)
       return [images count];

    return 10;
}
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {
    NSLog(@"tag = %d",tableView.tag);
 if (tableView.tag == 1)
 {
    NSLog(@"indexpath images %d %d",indexPath.row,[images count]);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if(cell == nil)
   {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

   }
   if ([images count] > [indexPath row])
       return cell;


   [cell.contentView addSubview:[images objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
   [cell.contentView sizeToFit];
   return  cell;
```

}

The table is not shown (no scrolling, no rows...blank view). And in fact, the NSLog is not getting called. (images contain 2 items).
Any syggestion?

Comment: Did you check if self.previewView != nil in debugger to make sure your xib is configured properly ? Maybe you didn't connect it to this property in Builder

Comment: check that is self.previewView is add in to you self.view or not? might be your table-view add successfully in to previewView but might be previewView not in superview

Comment: Grzegorz Krukowski and  Nitin Gohel you should have read the code, the tableview isn't retrieved from a IBOutlet but is created in viewDidLoad

Comment: @JeromeDiaz but read the comment what we are saying he is not adding tableview into self.view he is adding table view into customeview

Comment: @JeromeDiaz we are asking about self.previewView not previewTableView

Comment: The answers do not work. If I put the tableView outside the rect of previewView, I can see the table. Otherwise, I can not.

Comment: @Gregorz yes I checked. It is not nil. However, tag is never != 0.

Comment: @giuseppe: Please post the numberOfRows method

Comment: Sorry to bother. But still no success. See the edited code. I can not see the UITableView inside the previewView. The problem is also that heightForRow is never called.

Answer (score 3):

you have to specify the frame for the tableview while creating programatically.
ex:

```
tab2 = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 540, 768, 600)];
```

if you want table to occupy full screen.

```
tab = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Comment: It does not work. See the edited code. In the logs, tag always = 0

Comment: your are adding the subview like this. [self.previewView addSubview:previewTableView]. what is previewView there if it is another view declared, add it to the view, i have tried same code by changing [self.view addsubview:previewTableView] it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
previewTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
```

use:

```
previewTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(101, 45, 100, 416)];
```

Your numberOfRows must return more than 0.

Comment: Remember to check the numOfRowsInSection, as Midhun wisely suggested.